# Which method should I use to get Android Build Version SDK_INT?

Tags: qt, qtandroidextras

Android Extra has a function QtAndroid::androidSdkVersion() can get API Level, which introduced in Qt 5.3.

```
if (QtAndroid::androidSdkVersion() >= 23)
```

Recently I found there is another way in QOperatingSystemVersion introduced in Qt 5.9

```
if (QOperatingSystemVersion::current() >= QOperatingSystemVersion::AndroidMarshmallow)
```

Which way is more recommended?

Comment: anyone, it depends on your taste

Comment: In my opinion, the second option is better, because it is clear in the source as to what the value "23" means (i.e. QOperatingSystemVersion::AndroidMarshmallow).